# Switch windows using the mouse wheel

Tags: mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

Since the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, I still use Firefox but I am unable to put  the mouse over the Firefox icon and use the unpressed mouse wheel to scan through and open pages/tabs.

Have had a good look in settings without success.

Answer (score 2):

By default, scrolling on the icon in the dock indeed does nothing. If you wish that scrolling on an icon changes between different windows of an app, then change the setting either using `dconf-editor` or with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

To undo, use the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action
```

Note that, for Firefox, this will allow you to cycle between different open windows, but not between different tabs in the same window. In previous Ubuntu versions with Unity desktop, that also was not the case.

Comment: Thanks so much, windows are now cycling by mouse roller.

Comment: It's stuff like this that utterly makes my Desktop experience - and my day. I'm incredibly happy to have this feature back and wish I could give more than one upvote. :)